# Status of Gnome Graphics with ATI Cards in 11.10

Tags: gnome, ati, fglrx

Has there been any fix yet for the graphics problem?  Removing fglrx and installing 11.9 from ATI hoses my system so I'm not going to bother for now.  My understanding is there is a fix but it has not been released yet.

Thanks - my first question!

Comment: just use the 11.8 packages for 11.10, these are mostly trouble free

Comment: No, unfortunately 11.8 does not work. The generic driver that was installed during a clean install works, but the video card (ATI 5800) is over heating with the fan running constantly. Install fglrx, and the fan stops running, but the menu bar has distorted colors with letters missing (Gnome 3.2).

Comment: Then you need to the default open source packages until ATI releases better drivers, nothing you can do easy to solve that.

Comment: Well, new drivers have are out 11.10.  Anybody try them?

Comment: These have been fixed in Catalyst 11.10 which got released today. http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTAwODg

Comment: Just did now, they look very very good, even gnome-shell is reported to work. Videos are playing perfect with no problems on my system. [here](http://www.uptechtalk.com/?p=86) are instructions on how to install the driver for 32/64bits.

Answer (score 1):

The way to install ati 11.10 drivers, working on my Hp Dv5 1135 and using right now gnome-shell

**1. Uninstall all previews drivers with:** 
*If you get any error in any of these steps just repeat it*

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*

sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati

sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

***Restart your Computer***

**2. Install the necesary packages:**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
```

*if you're runing the 64 bit version of ubuntu don't forget to install this:*

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

**3. Download the new drivers with:**

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-10-x86.x86_64.run
```

**4. Create the package**

*Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric*

```
sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-10-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric
```

*Ubuntu 11.04 Natty*

```
sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-10-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/natty
```

**5. Install the package**

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb

sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

RESTART YOU COMPUTER

***Note:***
Open CompizConfig Settings Manager **CCSM** if you don't have it install it go to Open GL option and deactive the vertical blank syncro option

If you get some error just uninstall the new drivers following just the first step

Hope it helps